# In R, can't set names of vector elements using assignment in combine function

Tags: r

Quick question. Why does the following work in R (correctly assigning the variable value "Hello" to the first element of the vector):

```
> a <- "Hello"
> b <- c(a, "There")
> b
[1] "Hello" "There"
```

And this works:

```
> c <- c("Hello"=1, "There"=2)
> c
Hello There 
    1     2
```

But this does not (making the vector element name equal to "a" rather than "Hello"):

```
> c <- c(a=1, "There"=2)
> c
    a There 
    1     2
```

Is it possible to make R recognize that I want to use the value of a in the statement `c <- c(a=1, "There"=2)`?

Comment: An aside: Ack! You're masking the function `c()` with a variable! Danger! Danger, Will Robinson!

Comment: Oops again. So I shouldn't name a variable 'c'? I contemplated editing my question, but I'll leave it for educational purposes.

Comment: It's not catastrophic, but in general you should avoid common functions as variables. `c()`, `data()` and `t()` are the most common ones people try to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure how `c()` internally creates the names attribute from the named objects. Perhaps it is along the lines of `list()` and `unlist()`?  Anyway, you can assign the values of the vector first, and the names attribute later, as in the following.

```
a <- "Hello"
b <- c(1, 2)
names(b) = c(a, "There")
b
# Hello There 
#     1     2
```

Then to access the named elements later:

```
b[a] <- 3
b
# Hello There 
#     3     2 
b["Hello"] <- 4
b
# Hello There 
#     4     2
b[1] <- 5
b
# Hello There 
#     5     2
```

**Edit**

If you really wanted to do it all in one line, the following works:

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("c(",a," = 1, 'there' = 2)")))
# Hello there 
# 1     2
```

However, I think you'll prefer assigning values and names separately to the `eval(parse())` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the values in a named list.  Then unlist it.  e.g.

lR<-list("a" = 1, "There" = 2 )

v = unlist(lR)

this gives a named vector v

v

```
a There 
1     2
```